# Local fabric binaries and docker images are out of sync. This may cause problems

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I was trying to build my first network. While executing

```
./byfn.sh generate script
```

When I am executing

```
./byfn.sh
```

it shows the below error:

[image: error output screenshot]

Thereafter -- deleted the existing and then downloaded the higher version of Hyperledger Fabric using the command:

```
cd fabric-samples
rm -Rf bin
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.3.0
./scripts/bootstrap.sh
```

But again an error occurred:

[image: error output screenshot]

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. They are hard to read and links can break. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove all the images of the fabric. Then download the images from the link given below.It will be in sync with your current fabric setup. (1.4.6)

```
   curl (tiny url from the fabric) | bash -s -- 1.4.6 1.4.6 0.4.18
```

(Not allowed to post the tiny url here, so copy that from fabric samples download page)

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using the new test-network that came with Fabric 2.0.  It's much better organized and easier to follow:  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/test_network.html